# Recursive shared library loading - Cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, shared-libraries, codeblocks

I am compiling an application which consists of several projects, that generate dynamic libraries (Shared Libraries on LINUX). Of course that different projects are linking to the others that I've compiled. I am using CodeBlocks 10 under Ubuntu, using GCC compiler.

Due to the fact that, according to the arguments specified by the user, different libraries shall be loaded, in my main application I am loading the appropriate library, according to the decision, with the following line:

```
dll = dlopen("my_library.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

As specified in documentation, the dlopen loads libraries automatically If  the  library has dependencies on other shared libraries and the process is done recursively.

The problem is that right after my dlopen, I call dlerror() in order to understand what's going on and I get the following error:

> ../../../../gccDebug/os.so : Cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory.

Just looking at the error, I completly understand it, because it is looking 2 folders below more than it should. The question is why?

What I mean is: I use relative paths to explicitly load Shared Libraries on the projects. On my Main Application, the Working Directory is ../../gccDebug. 
I load, using dlopen, mylibrary.so, which explicitly loads (in project Options) ../../gccDebug/gui.so. This gui.so then also explicitly loads (in project options) ../../gccDebug/so.os

What it seems to me that is happening, is that he is appending the paths making that on the 3rd "iteration" he is looking for a path which is already searching too many folders back than it should. If the first recursive loading (gui.so) works just fine, why does the 2nd recursive loading (so.os) is giving a strange path??

What is wrong with the recursive loading of the shared libraries using dlopen function?

Comment: What do you mean "in project options"?

Comment: Codeblocks Build Options

Answer (score 2):

Each path should be relative to the library doing the loading, so for `../../gccDebug/gui.so` to load something in the same directory it should load `./gui.so`

The extra `../..` are because you've told something in `../../gccDebug` to load something in ../../gccDebug`_relative to itself_ which relative to your program's working directory is`../../gccDebug/../../gccDebug`i.e.`../../../gccDebug`

Do that a few times for different libraries and you'll get the number of unwanted `..` components you're seeing.

Are you sure that `gui.so` actually loaded? Could it be that `mylibrary.so` had copied the `../../gccDebug/os.so` dependency from `gui.so` at link-time and so at run-time was trying to load that before loading `gui.so`?

Have you use `ldd mylibrary.so` to see what it tries to find?  You can also use `readelf -d mylibrary.so` to see the contents of the dynamic section of the library.

Comment: Yes I guess it copied during link time. The thing is, I have the same project under Windows and Linux, both on Codeblocks. While on WINDOWS he can manage to resolve the relative paths without any problem, on Linux with the dlopen ONLY (because loading explicitly the libraries using Project Build options of CB causes no problem) it is appending the paths so that eventually I get such a stupid path which makes completely no sense. And I don't think that I have to move all my libraries to the position he wants just "BECAUSE". There must be a way just like there is on Windows, am I right?

Comment: Yes, just make the paths to each shared library relative to the library that loads it, not the executable

Comment: I am loading each Library relative to the location of the project file (.cbp) which is loading it.

Comment: I don't know anything about codeblocks, but it's the runtime linker that loads libraries, not codeblocks, so I don't understand what you're doing